# Two twitter follow buttons with addthis, one extra twitter follow button

Tags: html, css, twitter, addthis

Yesterday, an extra twitter follow button started showing up in the AddThis section on a site, so there were two identical twitter follow buttons. AddThis puts the buttons in with JavaScript. It must be an AddThis or Twitter bug, because there was only one link for twitter in the addthis section in the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today it seems to have been fixed, but this might be useful in the future. I fixed it by hiding the second Twitter follow button:

```
iframe.twitter-follow-button + iframe.twitter-follow-button { display: none; }
```